# Optional column in sqlAlchmey table

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, model

I need to import some sqlite databases to a postgresql data base unfortunately in some of the sqlite databases are some columns missing.

I'd like to use the same model for all the databases and if one column is missing, it should just initialize the variable corresponding to it to None.

I'd imagine the syntax would be like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
import sqlalchemy.orm

TableBase = sql.orm.declarative_base()

class ExampleTbl(TableBase):
    __tablename__ = "example"
    
    # ... other columns
    optional = sql.Column(sql.Text, if_not_exsits=None) # optional should be None if the column does not exists
    # ... other columns
```

It probably isn't as easy as setting a flag but how could I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I can actually find out if the column is in the table before querying it. So if sqlalchemy doesn't support it out of the box I could probably write a function that generates the required table that would match the one in the database but I would prefer something easier.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm going to do the approach that I suggested in the first edit, I've run in some problems so I'm going make a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656865/define-sqlalchmey-tables-based-on-function-input).

Comment: "I need to import some sqlite databases to a postgresql data base" - how does this  model fit into this process?

Comment: It doesn't it is just an example

Comment: So, you want to import data from one database to another, using SQLAlchemy, but the tables in the source database(s) don't always have all the columns as those in the target database, is that right?  Are the SQLAlchemy models only for the import or are they used for other purposes as well?

Comment: Yes basically i need to restructure the source databases a little bit   Including unifying the two database layouts which are practically the same except one is missing some columns.  And yes the entire application is only doing that.

Comment: Are you getting the error in a `select` or what?

Comment: Can you show how you expect to use such a model?